# What is the most effective data structure to use in my Neural Network program? Does my program require dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a background in Java and am trying to learn C++. I am currently trying to write a neural network program, but I am struggling with some fundamental concepts with regards to memory allocation. My question is primarily concerned with the **Network** class.

In the **Network** constructor I need to initialize an array of pointers to arrays of **Neuron** objects and pass it to the **Network** class variable *layers*. I do not believe I need to use any dynamic memory allocation (i.e. vectors) because I know the size of the arrays at compile time (obviously correct me if I'm wrong here). Should I be declaring the arrays in the constructor and then extending their scope with *unique_ptr*? or is there a way to initialize the arrays as a class variable and somehow define their sizes in the constructor.

Any suggestions on other parts of my code is also welcome. I am trying to learn as much as I can here.

Also where can I find resources on this stuff? All of the c++ resources I have found cover only the basics.

**Network.h**

```
class Network {
public:
    size_t numLayers;
    size_t* layerSizes;
    //array of ptrs to array of Neurons
    /*here I essentially need a two dimensional array of neurons
    where each column is a layer (array) of neurons in the network*/
    vector<unique_ptr<Neuron[]>> layers;
    Network (void){};       //input nodes
    Network (size_t[], size_t);
};
```

**Network.cpp**

```
Network::Network (size_t structure[], size_t size) {
/*structure is an array of values indicating the size of each layer
i.e for an xor nnet structure would equal {2,2,1} for 2 input nodes
2 hiden nodes and 1 output node */

//total number of layers
numLayers = size;   
//number of nodes in each respective layer                  
layerSizes = structure;

for (size_t l = 1; l < size; l++) {
    size_t arraySize = structure[l];
    Neuron temp[arraySize]; //initialize array with default Neurons
    for (size_t n = 0; n < arraySize; n++) {
        temp[n] = Neuron(/*array of Neurons in previous layer, array of random weights, size, threshold*/);
    }
}
```

}

**Neuron.h**

```
class Neuron {
public:
    //ptr to array of connecting neurons
    Neuron** synapse;
    //equal sized array of corresponding weights    
    double* weights;    
    //length of the synapse and weight arrays;
    size_t size;        
    double threshold, value;
    Neuron (void);      //input nodes
    void initialize (Neuron*[], double[], size_t, double);
    int propagate(void);
};
```

**Neuron.cpp**

```
//default constructor
Neuron::Neuron (void) {}

void Neuron::initialize (Neuron* connects[], double initial_weights[], size_t arraySize, double thresh) {
    synapse = connects;
    weights = initial_weights;
    size = arraySize;
    threshold = thresh;
}

int Neuron::propagate (void) {
    double inputSignal = 0.0;
    //sum the weights*values of each connecting node
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; i++){
        inputSignal += *(weights+i) * (**(synapse+i)).value;
    }
    inputSignal += (-1 * threshold);
    value = 1.0/(1.0 + exp(-inputSignal));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you can't "extend the scope" of an automatic storage duration object with `unique_ptr`.

Comment: What Makes You Think that Capitlaizing Almost Every Word is an Effective Way to Communicate?

Comment: With arrays of pointers to Neurons, you would still have to allocate the actual Neurons somewhere and then point to them.  Instead, you  can aggregate the Neurons in vectors directly.  Also, it looks advisable to introduce a Layer class between your Network and Neuron classes, which will allow you to have layers of different sizes - i.e. Network will have a vector of Layers and each Layer will have a vector of Neurons.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors can be dynamically sized, but that doesn't mean that using vectors commits you to dynamic memory allocation. As a rule, an STL vector is a superior alternative to a raw C-style array, and should be preferred in the absence of very good reasons otherwise.  You can also take advantage of the many ways in which vectors can be initialized.

In particular, if you introduce an explicit class to model a layer, you can have code like this, where the initialization of all the Neurons in the Network is taken care of automatically.  (This is illustrative only).

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

class Neuron
{
public:
    Neuron(); 

    void propagate( std::vector<Neuron> const& layer, std::vector<double> const& weights, double thresh );

private:
    double  value_;
};

void Neuron::propagate( std::vector<Neuron> const& layer, std::vector<double> const& weights, double thresh )
{
    for ( size_t index{0}; index < layer.size(); ++index )
    {
        thresh -= layer[index].value_ * weights[index];
    }
    value_ = 1.0 / ( 1.0 + std::exp( thresh ) );
}

class Layer
{
public:
    Layer(size_t size);

    void propagate( Layer const& previous, double thresh );

private:
    std::vector<Neuron>     neurons_;
    std::vector<double>     weights_;
};

void Layer::propagate( Layer const& previous, double thresh )
{
    for ( auto& neuron : neurons_ )
    {
        neuron.propagate( previous.neurons_, previous.weights_, thresh ); 
    }
}

class Network
{
public:
    Network(size_t structure[], size_t size);

private:
    std::vector<Layer>      layers_;
};

Neuron::Neuron() : value_(0) {}
Layer::Layer(size_t size) : neurons_(size), weights_(size, (1.0 / size)) {}
Network::Network(size_t structure[], size_t size) : layers_(structure, structure + size) {}

int main(void)
{
    size_t  sizes[] = { 2, 2, 1 };
    Network     _network(sizes, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, three different ways to initialize vectors have been used.  You can read about them [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/)

Note also that the Network "matrix" consists of Neurons, not of pointers to Neurons.  You probably don't need that extra level of indirection.